# rubycas-client authentification and local session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rubycas, rubycas-client

I am using ruby-cas client, for an authentification based on a CAS.
I would like to link the ruby_cas authentication to my application :

when we log in with cas, in additon to the CAS session created, a session for my application is also created.

What should i do?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) and [devise_cas_authenticatable](https://github.com/nbudin/devise_cas_authenticatable)

This should work for Rails 3. I am trying to make it work with rails 4 but [rubycas-client](https://github.com/rubycas/rubycas-client) (needed for devise_cas_authenticatable) is giving me a lot of trouble. However I haven't surrendered yet :)

Comment: I managed to make devise and devise_cas_authenticatable work without trouble, rubycas-client alone did not work for me in Rails 4. In order to make devise check for cas authentication in every call, just delete the user session in a before_filter (before_action).