# How to turn a Rails app with Devise into a SSO/CAS server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cas

I realized from a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25878009/how-to-turn-a-rails-app-with-devise-into-an-oauth-provider) that I had been asking the wrong question...I would like to turn my application into a CAS server so that admins of the application may use this same authentication mechanism to log into other applications that we develop for the organization.

Have you done this before? Is there a plugin which adds the ability to Devise to be able to act as a CAS server? What do I need to change/add in order to turn the app into a CAS server?

Answer (score 4):

Check this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21615670/rubycas-client-authentification-and-local-session/), that explains rails 4 issues with [devise_cas_authenticatable](https://github.com/nbudin/devise_cas_authenticatable/) gem.

For the Server, you may use [CASino](http://casino.rbcas.com) for the server, it looks very clean. Check its [installation guide](http://casino.rbcas.com/docs/installation/).

OR

An Alternative solution, if both apps are on the same domain and they share the same database, you can simply modify the session cookie to be universal for all subdomains on your specified domain.

Comment: `devise_cas_authenticatable` is used for creating a client, not a server. So it requires that you already have a CAS server running somewhere else.

Comment: @Andrew I've updated my answer, if that is what you needed, you may find this [article](http://bentoncreation.com/post/74392403766/devise-cas-using-devise-cas-authenticatable-and) helpful.

Comment: This is the correct link [article](https://jeremysmith.co/posts/2014-01-24-devise-cas-using-devisecasauthenticatable-and-casino/)